data.aws_subnets Tag Filter Applies With Value "Private" But Not "Public"
Description
I have a VPC with 2 public subnets and 2 private subnets in an EC2 VPC. I am attempt to filter a data.aws_subnets declaration down to just the public subnets using a tag filter as per this doc. This works as intended when the value is "public" but doesn't work when the value of the tag filter is "Public"
I'm trying to figure out why this is and if "Public" is a reserved word either for Terraform or AWS.
Terraform
data "aws_vpc" "env_default" {
  cidr_block = var.default_vpc_cidr[var.env_name]
}

data "aws_subnets" "public_subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.env_default.id]
  }

  tags = {
    Tier = "Public"
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "private_subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.env_default.id]
  }

  tags = {
    Tier = "Private"
  }
}


Console Output
> module.defaults.test_3
{
  "filter" = toset([
    {
      "name" = "vpc-id"
      "values" = toset([
        "vpc-0a017736383e3fb28",
      ])
    },
  ])
  "id" = "us-west-2"
  "ids" = tolist([
    "subnet-0374050527a12267f",
    "subnet-00c787547c5ee8a08",
  ])
  "tags" = tomap({
    "Tier" = "Private"
  })
  "timeouts" = null /* object */
}
> module.defaults.test_2
{
  "filter" = toset([
    {
      "name" = "vpc-id"
      "values" = toset([
        "vpc-0a017736383e3fb28",
      ])
    },
  ])
  "id" = "us-west-2"
  "ids" = tolist([
    "subnet-0374050527a12267f",
    "subnet-0ea230b36bf53ffa5",
    "subnet-00c787547c5ee8a08",
    "subnet-0b40a33beb489cae5",
  ])
  "tags" = tomap(null) /* of string */
  "timeouts" = null /* object */
}


Well, the second output says "tags" = tomap(null), so to me it seems the value for tags hasn't been provided.

I agree that the value isn't showing up in the output but I do not understand why it's missing from the first place given the content of the .tf files.

This is the exact code you are using? It was not taken from the example in the docs? The second output seems to list all the subnets.

The private subnet example is straight from the docs. The public one is a modification I made that I assumed would work exactly given that it's almost a strict copy.
